# Echo JSON before script terminates in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently trying to echo a JSON from a PHP script before my function terminates. After some research I've got the following solution:

```
    Yii::log("STARTED");

    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

    @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

    ob_start();
    $res = array("res" => "test");
    echo json_encode($res);

    // get the size of the output
    $size = ob_get_length();

    // send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header('Connection: close');

    // flush all output
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    // close current session
    if (session_id()) session_write_close();

    sleep(10);
    Yii::log("My task");
```

The JSON is sent correctly to the browser however after closing the current session my script terminates (i.e. I don't see "My task" in the log). Any suggestion?

Comment: Please correct your post title. According to your information, you ARE echoing the JSON before the script ends. The problem is that your log entry is not being written.

Comment: Hi, the call to Yii::log is just an example, any other function I call after flush is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just print some json to the browser this code will be enough:

```
Yii::log("STARTED");
$res = array("res" => "test");
echo CJSON::encode($res);
// close current session
if (session_id()) session_write_close();

sleep(10);
Yii::log("My task");
```